# Creating an Order

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a problem with using the `useEffect` method as such on creating an order component, upon checking on my data base it passes 2 data instead of 1 data. So, I really need help on this one as I'm only a beginner on react.
Tried putting the creating of order in a function, and calling the function but it keeps looping the entire function

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/orders`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
      .then((result) => result.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('Order data: ', data)
        setOrder(data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);
```

```
const fetchOrder = () => {
    fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/orders`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
      .then((result) => result.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setOrder(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchOrder();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have written two fetch functions and both Methods are in POST so it does the same fetching but you are calling only fetchOrder() which is fine.

1. Please remove the duplicate one first
2. try using  async/await.

Use async/await instead of promise chains: Async/await syntax provides a more readable and synchronous-looking code structure. It allows you to write asynchronous code in a more sequential manner.

````
const headers = {
  Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};

const fetchOrder = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/orders`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    setOrder(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  fetchOrder();
}, []);```
````